# Wordpress Plugin: Parent Category Toggler - Add action to Posts screen bulk edit

Tags: wordpress

I have installed this plugin which allows automatic selection of parent categories in the Posts screen:

https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/parent-category-toggler/trunk/parent-category-toggler.php

The plugin works fine when editing an individual post on its own page. I needed to add the following line of code to get Quick Edit to work however:

```
    add_action('admin_footer-edit.php', 'super_category_toggler');
```

The issue that I have is that no matter what I try I cannot get it to work in the Edit Posts bulk actions menu on the main Posts page. Can anyone possibly help me out with this please? I'm a Wordpress novice and I'm kinda lost.

Comment: It looks like you already asked the support forum for the plugin for help and found this line of code in another older answer. This may be deprecated now, but, you can try adding it to your THEME's `functions.php` file

Comment: Tried that and still no go. Looks like I'm going to have to really dig into this to figure it out.

Comment: I got tired of trying to figure this out and just installed this instead:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/yummi-auto-check-parent-category-category-tree-checklist/

The Parent Category Toggler is simpler but isn't maintained anymore anyway. The Parent Category AutoCheck + Category Tree Checklist plugin works great and actually has support.